# Cannot assign to 'MyComponent' because it is not a variable (react-dnd multi drag&drop support in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-dnd

I would like to have drag and drop at the same time using `react-dnd`

```
// ... imports ...
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render () {
    const { connectDragSource, isDragging, connectDropTarget, isOver } = this.props

    return connectDragSource(connectDropTarget(
      <div style={{ opacity: isDragging ? 0.5 : 1 }} >
        Just an example
     </div>
    ))
  }
}

MyComponent = DragSource('MyComponent', elementSource, (connect, 
monitor) => ({
  connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
  isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
}))(MyComponent);

MyComponent = DropTarget('MyComponent', elementTarget, connect => ({
  connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
}))(MyComponent);

export default MyComponent;
```

I found that it is possible in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257882/react-dnd-make-a-component-draggable-and-droppable-at-the-same-time). However, In my environment I get this error:

```
Cannot assign to 'MyComponent' because it is not a variable [.ts(2539)]
```

I am using TypeScript (.ts). Could this be the problem? If so, How can achieve same thing in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of trying to reassign your class name, just use new names:

```
class MyComponent extends ...

const MyComponent2 = DragSource(...)(MyComponent);
const MyComponent3 = DropTarget(...)(MyComponent2);
export default MyComponent3;
```

The only thing that matters is that you eventually `export default` the version you want callers to use when they import `MyComponent`.